# android recording volume change

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

Now I am working on a Android application to record voice. I did this by using the following code.

```
m_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    m_recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

    m_recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 // m_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
    m_recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128);
    m_recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

    m_recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio.3gp");
        try {
            m_recorder.prepare();
            m_recorder.start();
        }
```

But the problem is I am getting Low volume sounds.I had searched online for solution.All I got was

> "There is no way to do this while recording - but while playing, you
>   can use the setVolume(float, float) method on MediaPlayer."

But I have to upload the recorded clip on the server.So is there any way to convert the low volume sound clip to high volume clip?

Answer (score -3):

I used this code for recording and saving the file and it worked for me:

```
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileNameStr,
                            MODE_PRIVATE);

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(fos.getFD());
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
```

Comment: what does these lines do m_recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128);
    m_recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

Comment: i used that line for improving sound quality......i tried ur code....what is that filenamestr variable?...

Comment: Is my code working for u... Filenamestr is a string variable which holds filename

Comment: It is stored in phone memory I guess.... You can use fileNameStr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio.3gp";